# ModuleNotFoundError when installing packages

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pygame, pycharm, winreg

I've been having a problem with installing packages in PyCharm. This started happening a few months ago, but before that it was fine. I can install it from the cmd using pip, but when I try to import it into the IDE it gives this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_winreg'
```

and isn't available for use. The package I'm trying to install right now is pygame, but it has had trouble with other ones. I tried to make sure I have winreg installed by using 'pip3 install winreg' in the cmd, but it gives error text saying, "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement winreg." What am I doing wrong?

Also, if it helps, I'm using Windows and the latest version of PyCharm, as well as python 3. Thanks for the help, I've been looking for a while now.

Comment: Why are you trying to import `_winreg` rather than `winreg`?

Answer (score 0):

I think one of your problems possibly is that you didn't add pygame in your project interpreter. (To add it go to File -> Settings -> Project Interpreter then click the green plus sign and search for pygame.) I don't know if this will work for winreg, but tell me if it does.

Comment: I didn't know about the Project Interpreter until I read this, actually, but unfortunately it gives me that same error when I try to install pygame from there. :(

Answer (score 0):

I can't find `_winreg` anywhere, I've searched `winreg`'s file, and modules , there don't seems like any of `_winreg`. I think you probably want to import `winreg`, not `_winreg`.

And also, if you are using PyCharm's venv, you need to use the project's prompt to import,or project interpreter.

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement` sometime means your python's version is too new for the module to use.